# How to Delete All Product Metadata with SQL using SKU

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to delete everything belonging to products with certain SKU. Post-metals like _price, _stock_status, or the categories it's attached to are basically everything. Also, my DBMS mysql.

I wrote a SQL code for this but it doesn't work. I couldn't find where the error is.
I want to delete all products containing ABCDE sku (ABCDE1, ABCDE2 etc.).

**Update:** I noticed that the SQL code is not working because the target table has been updated.
The SQL code is currently running. However, there is a new problem. Count values are not updating on WP-admin > category page and attribute page. So, the number seems high, as if there is a product.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type='product' 
AND ID IN (
  SELECT post_id FROM (
    SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%ABCDE%'
  ) AS temp_table
);

DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
  WHERE post_type='product' 
  AND ID IN (
    SELECT post_id FROM (
      SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%ABCDE%'
    ) AS temp_table
  )
);

DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE object_id IN (
  SELECT post_id FROM (
    SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%ABCDE%'
  ) AS temp_table
);

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN (
  SELECT post_id FROM (
    SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%ABCDE%'
  ) AS temp_table
);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so] please read the [tour] and [ask] . Please specify your DBMS

Comment: Maybe you could make a temporal table, fill it with SKU and join the deleted table with the temporal one

Comment: Thank you. I will review. I also added: MySQL. Also i guess you didn't see that I updated the question. The only problem right now is counting.

Comment: If you configure all the tables with foreign keys and `ON DELETE CASCADE`, deleting the SKU from the main table should automatically propagate to all the dependent tables.

Answer (score 0):

Because the count values are stored in the **wp_term_taxonomy** table.
You can update the count values in the wp_term_taxonomy table:

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy
SET count = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships
  WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
)
WHERE taxonomy IN ('product_cat', 'pa_attribute');
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixed the problem for this category. What should I add for the attribute values count?

Comment: you can change the query: 
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy
SET count = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
)
WHERE taxonomy IN ('product_cat', 'product_tag', 'product_brand', 'pa_%', 'your_custom_attribute_prefix%');

The 'pa_%' wildcard in the query is meant to cover all the product attributes. The 'pa_' prefix is the standard prefix for product attributes in WooCommerce.

However, if you have custom attributes with a different prefix replace "your_custom_attribute_prefix%" with the prefix for your custom attr

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Maybe I'm translating it wrong. For example, Color is an attribute and Blue is the attribute's value. As you know, their number appears in the admin panel. But I was not able to update it (eg blue number). It looks like there are still some products out there.